Can tensorflow optimize the extract_patches operation to avoid large redundant tensors?
I'm trying to implement a "sliding window attention" mechanism, where each pixel in an image attends only to it's neighboring pixels (similar to a convolution, but with the weights determined by an attention matrix). The only way I know how to do this without looping over pixels or writing a custom operation in c++, is to use the tf$image$extract_patches function together with tf$enisum. I'm pretty sure my implementation works, but I'm concerned about how the size of the patches tensor will scale in an application. Here's the code:
h=w=20L
patch_size = 3L
embedding_dim = 5L
image_in = layer_input(shape = c(h, w, embedding_dim))

keys = layer_dense(image_in, units = embedding_dim, activation = NULL, use_bias = FALSE)
queries = layer_dense(image_in, units = embedding_dim, activation = NULL, use_bias = FALSE)
values = layer_dense(image_in, units = embedding_dim, activation = NULL, use_bias = FALSE)
keys = tf$image$extract_patches(keys, padding = 'SAME',
                                sizes = c(1L, patch_size, patch_size, 1L),
                                strides = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
                                rates = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L))
values = tf$image$extract_patches(values, padding = 'SAME',
                                  sizes = c(1L, patch_size, patch_size, 1L),
                                  strides = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
                                  rates = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L))
batch_size = tf$shape(image_in)[1]
keys = tf$reshape(keys, shape = c(batch_size, h, w, patch_size * patch_size, embedding_dim))
values = tf$reshape(values, shape = c(batch_size, h, w, patch_size * patch_size, embedding_dim))

# one query (axis 'l') times keys in the patch (axes 'ml') transposed, 
# resulting in weights in axis 'm',
# broadcasted over 'ijk' (batch, h,w),
attn = tf$einsum('ijkl,ijkml->ijkm', queries, keys)
attn = k_softmax(attn, axis = 4L)
# matrix multiply attn weights (axis 'l') with values (axes 'lm'),
# resulting in summed features in axis 'm'
attn_out = tf$einsum('ijkl,ijklm->ijkm', attn, values)

The patches are of shape (batch_size, h, w, patch_size^2, embedding_dim), which could be prohibitively big for even small patch sizes (and I want to use fairly large patches if possible). In an ideal scenario, I would like if tensorlow could represent the patches tensor using the same memory as the original image, but with a repetitive indexing scheme that creates a larger 'virtual' tensor. When I compute attention for a patch, I'm reusing most of the keys and values from overlapping patches.
My question is whether tensorflow is smart enough to make this optimization. I do not understand enough about tensoflow's graph optimization, and I don't know how to profile this sort of thing. If anyone has expertise on how tensorflow works at a low level, I would really appreciate some insight.
If the answer turns out to be no, is there some manual intervention I could make to optimize?
thanks
